# If I hide .php by .htaccess, I cannot login my web

Tags: php, .htaccess

If I hide my .php from every page, I cannot login my web, Its don't show any error also just display same login page. So I want to know, Where and what will I edit to login .htaccess or loginpage?

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

My login page:

```
<?php $site_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
if(!class_exists('MySQLDB')== true){
require_once($site_root ."/nav_top.php");}
?>
<?
include_once("include/session.php");

if($session->logged_in){
echo "You are logedIn";
}
else{
?>
<form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="process.php" method="POST">
<input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="user" value="<? echo $form->value("user"); ?>" placeholder="username">
<input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="password" value="<? echo $form->value("pass"); ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-success">
</form>  
<?   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<form...>` should have:

```
action="/process"
```

instead of `action="process.php"` since your 2nd rewrite rule is already adding `.php` in a URI.

You also need to ignore `POST` requests from your first redirect rule because `POST` data gets lost while doing external redirection.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank u so much sir. Glad to see you again here.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna just hide .php you can try this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ $1.php [L,E]
```